# C# and Selenium - wait times

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a login routine at the start of an automated test which, once the URL as loaded, enters a site ID, a username and a password before hitting login.

The problem is that login is being clicked before the password gets entered resulting in a failed login - the test is tripping over itself in its haste!

In the old JS days, I'd use `browser.wait(nnnn)` which would work well. So not so much waiting for an element to be present so much as waiting for SendKeys to do its stuff.

Is there a c# equivalent to browser.wait()?

Here's the (Experimental) code - actual data has been removed.

```
[TestFixture]
public class Chrome_Sample_test
{
    private IWebDriver driver;
    public string homeURL;


    [Test(Description = "Check SauceLabs Homepage for Login Link")]
    public void Login_is_on_home_page()
    {


        homeURL = "https:/<URL>/";
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(homeURL);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        IWebElement siteID;
       
        siteID = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='winp_SiteID']"));
     
        siteID.SendKeys("<Id>");


        IWebElement usrName;

        usrName = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='winp_UserID']"));

        usrName.SendKeys("<UsrName>");


        IWebElement usrPass;

        usrPass = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='winp_Password']"));

        usrPass.SendKeys("<UsrPass>");

       
        IWebElement logOn;

        logOn = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='btn_LogOn']"));

        logOn.Click();

      


        //IWebElement element =
        //driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href='/beta/login']"));
        //          Assert.AreEqual("Sign In", element.GetAttribute("text"));


    }


    [TearDown]
    public void TearDownTest()
    {
        driver.Close();
    }


    [SetUp]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        homeURL = "https://<UL>/";
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

    }


}
```

Comment: Hey, have you checked this? https://www.browserstack.com/guide/wait-commands-in-selenium-webdriver Didn't it help?

Comment: This should not be happening. It feels like something is a little wonky with InternetExplorerDriver. Are you able to use a modern browser for this, like Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari or Opera? (literally **any** browser except Internet Explorer). The `SendKeys`method absolutely should not be returning control back to the caller until the characters are all present in the password field. This feels like a bug.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Yes this WAS Chrome - it's our preferred browser. We tend to avoid IE :)